# Storing and reading custom info from app.config in .Net Framework

Tags: c#, config, app-config, .net-4.6.1

I have a .NET Framework 4.6 application with classes that when instatiated they need to construct a dictionary. The dictionary will have string keys and values and I would like to store them in the app.config. So for each class I need a section in the app.config with the custom info inside. How can I do this? so far I have this

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section type="Class1" name="Class1" />
  </configSections>

  <Class1>
    <Column1>Value1</Column1>
  </Class1>
</configuration>
```

Is this valid? And if so how can I read it from code? I found this but hasn't led me anywhere

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var section = config.GetSection(nameof(Class1));
```

Comment: Assuming Class1 extends [`ConfigurationSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationsection?view=netframework-4.8). Have you tried it?

Comment: never thought of that. you got an example?

Comment: This documentation is pretty comprehensive https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/2tw134k3(v=vs.100). Searching is difficult because it often returns results for deprecated ways of doing the same thing